# Android Test With Mockito Always Pass

Tags: android, mockito

// Its First Time To Use `Mockito FrameWork` For Testing . I need To Know Why It Always Pass when i use `AssertEqual` . I want To Test  `CalculateDistance` It Take Place As Parameters . when i use Fake data It always Pass

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FullMapScreenTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    Context context;
    Parcel parcel;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void TestcalculateDistance() {

        FullMapScreen fullMapScreen = mock(FullMapScreen.class);
        Place place = new Place(30.0508883, 31.2432764);
        place.distance = 1000.00;
        Place fakeplace = new Place(33.0508883, 31.2432764);
        fakeplace.distance = 0;
        String expectedDistance = fullMapScreen.calculateDistance(place);
        String fakeDistance = fullMapScreen.calculateDistance(fakeplace);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedDistance, fakeDistance);
        Assert.assertEquals(fullMapScreen.calculateDistance(place),
                fullMapScreen.calculateDistance(fakeplace));

    }
}
```

Method To Test

```
public String calculateDistance(Place p) {
    if (p.distance > 0) {
        if (selectedPlace.distance > 1000) {
            return Long.toString(Math.round(p.distance) / 1000) 
                    + getString(R.string.km);

        } else {
            return Long.toString(Math.round(p.distance)) 
                    + getString(R.string.meter);
        }
    } else {
        Location locationA = new Location("Point A");

        locationA.setLatitude(MainActivity.lat);
        locationA.setLongitude(MainActivity.lng);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");

        locationB.setLatitude(p.getLatitude());
        locationB.setLongitude(p.getLongitude());

        double actualDistance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

        if (actualDistance > 1000) {
            return Long.toString(Math.round(actualDistance) / 1000) 
                    + " " + getString(R.string.km_away);
        } else {
            return Long.toString(Math.round(actualDistance)) 
                    + " " + getString(R.string.meter_away);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use Mockito here (just JUnit). Try compile or log your code to find bug.

Comment: ok how can i use Mockito here ??

Comment: corrected indentation, line wrapping and fixed code/non-code sections